# SharePoint 2010 Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

On the development server everything was OK but after deployment there is an `ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.` Unfortunately, there is no way to directly debug failing web part so i've got only some log information (e.g. exception message above and code section shown below).
Here is a code throwing the exception:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://mysite"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("MySPList");
        foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
        {
            if (item["Code"].ToString() == code)
            {
                if (item["Favorites"] != null)
                {
                    if (item["Favorites"].ToString().Contains(web.CurrentUser.ID + ";#" + web.CurrentUser.Name))
                    {
                        // first case simple code 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // second case simple code 
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // second case simple code 
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was in the **List View Lookup Threshold** parameter:

- Login to **Central Administration**.
- In section **Application Management** click **Manage Web Applications**.
- Pick desired web application.
- In the ribbon above click **General Settings** and pick **Resource Throttling** from dropdown menu.
- Find the **List View Lookup Threshold** and change it's value (from 8 to 10 in my case).